collect duckdb query into two dataframes?
Say I have a csv file with
date,value
2020-01-01,1
2020-01-02,4
2020-01-03,5
2020-01-04,9
2020-01-05,2

I would like to read it with duckdb, do some preprocessing, and ultimately end up with a train and validation set as Polars dataframes
I could do:
train = duckdb.sql("""
    select *, avg(value) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row)
    from read_csv(my_data.csv) qualify date < make_date(2020,1,4)
""").pl()
val = duckdb.sql("""
    select *, avg(value) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row)
    from read_csv(my_data.csv) qualify date >= make_date(2020,1,4)
""").pl()

and this works, but doesn't it risk double-computing things?
Is there a way materialize two dataframes at once without double-computing things? Or should I just do
data = duckdb.sql('select *, avg(value) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row) from read_csv(my_data.csv)').pl()
train = data.filter(pl.col('date') < date(2020, 1, 4))
val = data.filter(pl.col('date') >= date(2020, 1, 4))

?

You could read the data once into a temp table: create table data as (select ... from read_csv())

I see you read data into Polars DataFrame anyway, so you can use partition_by:
train, val = (
    data
    .with_columns(p = pl.col.date >= datetime(2020,1,4))
    .partition_by("p", include_key = False)
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 ┆ 1     │
│ 2020-01-02 ┆ 4     │
│ 2020-01-03 ┆ 5     │
└────────────┴───────┘
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-04 ┆ 9     │
│ 2020-01-05 ┆ 2     │
└────────────┴───────┘

Another possible solution might be creating table in DuckDB and then filtering this table:
data = duckdb.sql("""
    drop table if exists temp_data;
    
    create temporary table temp_data as
    select 
        *,
        avg(value) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row)
    from read_csv(my_data.csv);
""")

train = duckdb.sql("select * from temp_data where date < make_date(2020,1,4)")
val = duckdb.sql("select * from temp_data where date >= make_date(2020,1,4)")

I've quickly tested all four approaches, and it looks like faster ones are partition_by and DuckDB temp table.
I'm not sure if pure streaming solution exists (yet) - unfortunately, LazyFrame doesn't support partition_by method or iterating over groups.

i'm just curious if it's possible to collect into multiple dataframes directly in duckdb

yep, I got it. I'm looking at it and so far I can't see a way to stream it into 2 different data frames without materializing it in DataFrame or table in DuckDB.
there's scan_csv in polars but it doesn't have partition_by method.
